# Migrating Laravel Sail to other server

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I want to move a laravel sail project from one server to another. How do I move the project folder, database, and docker images to the new server? I want to keep the changes in the project codes and database entries.

Is it possible to migrate all at once using docker method or I have to migrate them one by one manually using methods like cloning the project folder from git repo, exporting database from cli, docker image save/load, etc?

I tried docker export/save/load and commit push/pull, but I can't seem to get the docker and sail to run.

Comment: On the other server, as soon as you run `sail up -d` it should start creating your containers. The images, by default, are located in your `vendor` folder. To make things easy, make a .zip of your laravel directory and unzip it on your new server, see if that works. `but I can't seem to get the docker and sail to run` <<<=== make sure you have a reproducible example. Make sure you show your error messages (in `text`, not with images), update your original question with the errors